# "Scope to this" with multiple items in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I select multiple items in solution explorer and right click, I cannot find the menu item "scope to this" any longer.

Is there any way of limiting the view in the solution explorer tree to two or more separate directories/files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, but you can see `New Solution Explorer View` menu item next to `Scope to This` menu. So you can create multiple scope in multiple solution explorer view.

Comment: Thats is really great!

Comment: Nah its not  great. The wish to scope 12 files cant be solved by opening 12 windows lol. Anyway answered ^^.

Comment: After this, you can drag solution explorer windows on each other and group them in one view. Ain't perfect, but workable